# document_root on Google App Engine not recognized

Tags: symfony, google-app-engine, google-app-engine-php

I'm running a Symfony 4 app on Google App Engine with a flexible environment config.

`public/index.php` is the index path from the project root.

I have defined a `document_root: public`, but it is not recognized.

For example:

https://myproject.appspot.com/ returns a `404`.

https://myproject.appspot.com/public/index.php returns a `200`.

It doesn't matter if it's a php file or a static resource. I have to add `public` to the path to access anything. Of course the desired behavior is that `public` is my document root.

The relevant parts of my `app.yml` are here:

```
runtime: php
env: flex

runtime_config:
  document_root: public
```

This follows all the documentation I have found. Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Comment: I just tested this and works for me. My app has a single `index.php` under a `public` directory, and my `app.yaml` looks just like the above snippet. Can you give that a try?
Also can you look at the app logs in Cloud Console to see if there's some error when processing the request?

Comment: Yes, that worked, and in the process I see that was naming the config file `app.yml`, and not `app.yaml`. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you post this as an answer so we know the issue is solved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that I was using a `.yml` extension instead of `.yaml`.

Renaming the file from `app.yml` to `app.yaml` resolved the issue.